when use django rest framwork and django_filters, Can ‘query’ be partially effective？
import django_filters
from .models import  Drug
class DrugFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):  # drug filter
    class Meta:
        model = Drug
        fields = {
            "drug": ["icontains"],
            "drug_zh": ["icontains"],
            "drugncode": ["exact"],
        }


class DrugViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows drug to be viewed or edited.
    """

    queryset = Drug.objects.all().order_by("drugncode")
    serializer_class = DrugmarkSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = DrugFilter

but, all my APIs(list,read,update,patch,delete) include query parameters.
only 'list'  need the parameters.
...

    def get_filterset_class(self):
        if self.action in ["list"]:
            return DrugFilter
        return None
...

(it dose not work)
I am new to this,  any help would be appreciated.
[]

I don't really see what the problem is. Nobody will likely make a DELETE /api/drugs/14/?drug__icontains='bla' request, but if they do and the filter matches, it will remove the drug. It can thus be used as an extra security mechanism to prevent deleting the wrong drug.

I don't really see what the problem is. Nobody will likely make a DELETE request to /api/drugs/420/?drug__icontains=Tetrahydrocannabinol, but if they do and the filter matches, it will remove the drug. It can thus be used as an extra security mechanism to prevent deleting the wrong drug.
If you really want to use this, you can convert it into a property, like:
class DrugViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Drug.objects.all().order_by('drugncode')
    serializer_class = DrugmarkSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]

    @property
    def filterset_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return DrugFilter
        return None
But this might have unwanted side effects with code that thinks filterset_class is a class attribute.
